# JXTA Getting Started

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

please, can someone here help me out, i have been trying to study JXTA but i cant get the codes to work. can someone give me step by step guide on how to use JXTA 2.6 or 2.7 even 2.5 steps will be appreciated. please i have read the programmer's guide etc even ebooks such as mastering jxta, java p2p, jxta in a nutshell. please i need working simple examples like a jxta peer that exhange hellow world message that all i need to fix myself up. i really need steps on how to test this on a single pc

Comment: i'm also searching for the same thing..

Comment: Might be worth adding a pastie.org of what you've got so far? Also, browse the _Related_ items to the right hand side of this page - there should be some code samples there.

Comment: @halfer,   believe   me   i   have   codes   infact   i  have   even   tested   codes   written   in   ebooks   and  tutorials   yet   it   wont   work.   I  just   need   the  simplest   of  example   code   and  configuration   steps   of  two   jxta   app  that   runs   on ssame   pc,   even   if  they   just   exchange   'hello   world'   then   exits.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Practical JXTA II book available for reading online at Scribd?

Comment: have you done anything with jxta orr have you used   it successfully?  i   have   done   that,   thanks   though,  maybe   someone   should  just   put   up   jxta   step   by   step   guide   of   the  things   he   didd to get   it   to   work.  Just   simple   example   that  exchanges   hello   wordl.   Thats all   i   need.